# Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of hello.Country[] out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, fasterxml

I have rest url that gives me all countries - http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=volodiaL.

I use RestTemplate from spring 3 to parse returned json into java objects:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
Country[] countries = restTemplate.getForObject("http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=volodiaL",Country[].class);
```

When I run this code I get an exception:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of hello.Country[] out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1846149; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:691)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:685)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.handleNonArray(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:222)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:133)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2158)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    ... 7 more
```

Finally my Country class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Country {
    private String countryName;
    private long geonameId;

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public long getGeonameId() {
        return geonameId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return countryName;
    }
}
```

The problem is that returned json contains root element "geonames" which contains array of country elements like so:

```
{
"geonames": [
    {
        "continent": "EU",
        "capital": "Andorra la Vella",
        "languages": "ca",
        "geonameId": 3041565,
        "south": 42.42849259876837,
        "isoAlpha3": "AND",
        "north": 42.65604389629997,
        "fipsCode": "AN",
        "population": "84000",
        "east": 1.7865427778319827,
        "isoNumeric": "020",
        "areaInSqKm": "468.0",
        "countryCode": "AD",
        "west": 1.4071867141112762,
        "countryName": "Andorra",
        "continentName": "Europe",
        "currencyCode": "EUR"
    }
]
}
```

How to tell `RestTemplate` to convert each element of array into `Country` object?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
public class CountryInfoResponse {

   @JsonProperty("geonames")
   private List<Country> countries; 

   //getter - setter
}

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
List<Country> countries = restTemplate.getForObject("http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=volodiaL",CountryInfoResponse.class).getCountries();
```

It would be great if you could use some kind of annotation to allow you to skip levels, but it's not yet possible (see [this](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-781) and [this](http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/use-annotations-to-skip-levels))

Comment: this didnt work for me, still geting  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: it works when the output has more than one item in the list but failes when there is zero or one item in the output.

Answer (score 9):

Another solution:

```
public class CountryInfoResponse {
  private List<Object> geonames;
}
```

Usage of a generic **Object**-List solved my problem, as there were other Datatypes like Boolean too.

Comment: That works for me but it is kind of work around, I still did not get it why it was throwing exception while trying to map the JSON object into Country object

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was getting value of `<input type="text">` with JQuery and I did it like this:

```
var newUserInfo = { "lastName": inputLastName[0].value, "userName": inputUsername[0].value,
 "firstName": inputFirstName[0] , "email": inputEmail[0].value}
```

And I was constantly getting this exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
>    at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@39cb6c98; line: 1, column: 54] (through reference chain: com.springboot.domain.User["firstName"]).

And I banged my head for like an hour until I realised that I forgot to write `.value` after this`"firstName": inputFirstName[0]`.

So, the correct solution was:

```
var newUserInfo = { "lastName": inputLastName[0].value, "userName": inputUsername[0].value,
 "firstName": inputFirstName[0].value , "email": inputEmail[0].value}
```

I came here because I had this problem and I hope I save someone else hours of misery.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using an extra `Class` and `List<Object> genomes` you could simply use a `Map`.

The data structure translates into `Map<String, List<Country>>`

```
String resourceEndpoint = "http://api.geonames.org/countryInfoJSON?username=volodiaL";

Map<String, List<Country>> geonames = restTemplate.getForObject(resourceEndpoint, Map.class);

List<Country> countries = geonames.get("geonames");
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring-boot 1.3.3 the method exchange() for List is working
as in the related answer

[Spring Data Rest - _links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284282/spring-data-rest-links/36216842#36216842)

Comment: Please put meaning information in the post. **Only link** as a answer is discouraged in stackOverflow.